# predict value of curve in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Suppose I have the following vector of points:

```
X=[ 0.401   0.398   0.395   0.392   0.388   0.384   0.381   0.377   0.373   0.368   0.364   0.359   0.354   0.349   0.344   0.339   0.334   0.328   0.322   0.316   0.310   0.304   0.297   0.291   0.284   0.277   0.270   0.263   0.256   0.249   0.242   0.234   0.227   0.220   0.212   0.205   0.198   0.190   0.183   0.176   0.169   0.161   0.154   0.147   0.140   0.134   0.127   0.120   0.113   0.107   0.101   0.094   0.088   0.082   0.076   0.070   0.064   0.059   0.053   0.048   0.042   0.037   0.032   0.027   0.022   0.018   0.013   0.009   0.004   0.000   -0.004  -0.008  -0.012  -0.016  -0.019  -0.023  -0.026  -0.030  -0.033  -0.036  -0.039  -0.042  -0.045  -0.048  -0.050  -0.053  -0.055  -0.058  -0.060  -0.062  -0.064  -0.066  -0.068  -0.070  -0.072  -0.074  -0.076  -0.077  -0.079  -0.080];

Y=[0.347    0.362   0.377   0.393   0.409   0.426   0.442   0.459   0.477   0.494   0.512   0.530   0.548   0.567   0.585   0.604   0.622   0.641   0.659   0.678   0.696   0.715   0.733   0.750   0.768   0.785   0.801   0.817   0.833   0.848   0.863   0.876   0.890   0.902   0.914   0.925   0.935   0.945   0.953   0.961   0.969   0.975   0.981   0.986   0.990   0.993   0.996   0.998   0.999   1.000   1.000   0.999   0.998   0.996   0.994   0.991   0.988   0.984   0.979   0.974   0.969   0.963   0.957   0.951   0.944   0.937   0.930   0.922   0.914   0.906   0.898   0.889   0.881   0.872   0.863   0.855   0.846   0.837   0.827   0.818   0.809   0.800   0.791   0.782   0.773   0.764   0.755   0.747   0.738   0.729   0.721   0.712   0.704   0.696   0.688   0.680   0.672   0.664   0.656   0.649];
```

When I plot the points `X` and `Y`, this is what I get:

[image]

I want to calculate the value of 'Width' of the curve `W`.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the points are unordered, and so simply subtracting the last point by the first point won't work.  What you can do is use `max` and `min` on the `X` array to determine the width:

```
Width = max(X) - min(X);
```

It's certainly as simple as that!   FWIW, your title says one thing, but your question asks another.  Suggest you either edit your question or title for clarity.